# How to call all functions with name starting with given prefix?

Tags: python

In Python how to write such a function which will call all functions in current file with given prefix?

For example:

```
def prepare(self):
  # ??? to call prepare_1, prepare_2

def prepare_1(self):

def prepare_2(self):
```

How to write `prepare` so it will call all functions started with `prepare_`?

Comment: Frankly, I'd write a function decorator `@function_group(group_name, ...)` and a support function `call_function_group(group_name)`. Explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: Are these normal stand-alone functions, or are they all methods of a particular class?

Comment: What about function that take arguments?

Comment: @dhke Can you give an example, please?

Comment: @PM2Ring They are all methods of a particular class that must be called from function outside of that class

Comment: @FujiApple Didn't understand what you mean :( Can you give an example?

Comment: @vladon the questions asks to call all functions with a given prefix, but what if some of the functions require arguments?  i.e. `def prepare_3(self, x, y):`

Comment: @FujiApple They have no arguments instead of `self`, i.e. have same signature

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If these functions are methods of a class, use `dir(self)` to list all attributes of `self`.

```
class C:

    def prepare(self):
        print(dir(self))
        for name in dir(self):
            if name.startswith('prepare_'):
                method = getattr(self, name)
                method()

    def prepare_1(self):
        print('In prepare_1')

    def prepare_2(self):
        print('In prepare_2')

C().prepare()
```

Output:

```
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'prepare', 'prepare_1', 'prepare_2']
In prepare_1
In prepare_2
```

---

Update: if you want to call methods from outside of class C:

```
obj = C()
for name in dir(obj):
    if name.startswith('prepare_'):
        m = getattr(obj, name)
        print(m)
        m()
```

Output:

```
<bound method C.prepare_1 of <__main__.C object at 0x7f347c9dff28>>
In prepare_1
<bound method C.prepare_2 of <__main__.C object at 0x7f347c9dff28>>
In prepare_2
```

Comment: Messa, and if I call it outside of `C`, how can I call `method`? `C.method()`, `C.method(C)`, `method(C)` does not work :( Can you help, please?

Comment: Lets say `c` is an instance of `C`: `c = C()`. Then you can get `c`'s attributes: `dir(c)` and `c`'s method by name: `getattr(c, name)`.

Comment: Ok, but when I call the method: `method = getattr(c, name); method()` Python says: `unbound method prepare_xxx() must be called with T instance as first argument (got __metaclass__ instance instead)`. `method(c)`, `c.method()`, `c.method(c)` also do not work.

Comment: Messa, with `getattr(c, name)()` python also gives the same error `unbound method...`

Comment: Are you sure you are calling `getattr(c, name)` with lowercase `c` - the object, not the class? `getattr(class_, name)` return unbound method, `getattr(instance, name)` returns bound method.

Comment: The snippet I've added to the answer works for me. I'm using Python 3 (if it matters). I've renamed `c` to `obj` to make it more distinguishable.

Comment: Yes, I sure that my c is an object of a class C. Messa, can it give an error because I'm using Python 2.7?

Comment: I've tried it, it works for me even in Python 2.7. Exact the same code as in my answer.

Comment: Messa, sorry, it was my syntax mistake. Your variant works.

Answer (score 8):

Use [globals](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) to access global namespace, [dict.items](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=iteritems#dict.items) to iterate over it and [callable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#callable) and [str.startswith](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=startswith#str.startswith) to identify that function has name you wish and it's callable:

```
def prepare(self):
  for key, value in globals().items():
      if callable(value) and key.startswith('prepare_'):
          value()

def prepare_1(self):print 1

def prepare_2(self):print 2
```

Comment: Order of calls is not guaranteed.

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski It's ok, order is not required

Answer (score 2):

It's been asked for, so here's a quick hack:

```
import functools

class FunctionGroup(object):
   """
       Defines a function group as a list of functions that can be
       executed sequentially from a single call to the function group.

       Use
       @func_group.add
       def my_func(...):
           ...

       to add functions to the function group.

       `func_group(...)` calls the added functions one by one.

       It returns a list of the return values from all evaluated functions.

       Processing terminates when one of the function raises an
       exception and the exception is propagated to the caller.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.funcs = []

    def add(self, func):
        self.funcs.append(func)
        return func

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return [
            func(*args, **kwargs) for func in self.funcs
        ]


prepare_group = FunctionGroup()
```

Note that the `__call__()` implementation is rather primitive and does nothing to handle exceptions.

Usage example:

```
@prepare_group.add
def prepare_1():
    print "prep 1"

@prepare_group.add
def prepare_2():
    print "prep 2"

prepare_group()
```

Maybe abused to call methods, of course:

```
class C(object):
    def m(self):
       pass
c = C()
func_group.add(c.m)
```

Comment: This is nice approach. With more abstraction this becomes design pattern that a lot of applications uses; see Blinker and other event systems. https://pythonhosted.org/blinker/